# How can I modify my .htaccess to remove www from url's

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess is removing index.php and also forcing https at the moment, how can I modify it to remove www from url since urls with www are causing my ssl certificate to fail.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301] 

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_extension openssl.so
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Replacing "example.com" with your servername.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after your last rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.%{SERVER_NAME}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```